# Why sync.Mutex exists?

Tags: go, concurrency

Why `sync.Mutex` exists while we have `sync.RWMutex`? I can lock/unlock rw mutex. What is the main difference between them?

Comment: Why downvoted? It's a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that you could use a [`sync.RWMutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) whenever you need a [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex).

I think both exist because there are a lot of cases when a `sync.Mutex` is enough (you don't need read and write level locking), and the implementation of `sync.Mutex` is simpler: requires much less memory and is most likely faster.

`sync.Mutex` is just 8 bytes:

```
type Mutex struct {
    state int32
    sema  uint32
}
```

While `sync.RWMutex` is 8 + 16 = 24 bytes (it includes a `sync.Mutex`):

```
type RWMutex struct {
    w           Mutex  // held if there are pending writers
    writerSem   uint32 // semaphore for writers to wait for completing readers
    readerSem   uint32 // semaphore for readers to wait for completing writers
    readerCount int32  // number of pending readers
    readerWait  int32  // number of departing readers
}
```

Yes, you could say 8 or 24 bytes should not matter. And it doesn't as long as you only have a few mutexes.

But it's not uncommon to put the mutex into the struct it's ought to protect (either embed or a regular, named field). Now if you have a slice of these struct values, maybe even thousands of them, then yes, it will make a noticeable difference.

Also, if you just need a mutex, `sync.Mutex` gives you less chance of misusing it (you can't accidentally call `RLock()` because it doesn't have that method).

Answer (score 0):

A part from taking more space as mentioned by @icza, it is also less efficient in terms of execution time.

If we look at the source code of RWMutex.Lock:

```
// Lock locks rw for writing.
// If the lock is already locked for reading or writing,
// Lock blocks until the lock is available.
func (rw *RWMutex) Lock() {
    if race.Enabled {
        _ = rw.w.state
        race.Disable()
    }
    // First, resolve competition with other writers.
    rw.w.Lock()
    // Announce to readers there is a pending writer.
    r := atomic.AddInt32(&rw.readerCount, -rwmutexMaxReaders) + rwmutexMaxReaders
    // Wait for active readers.
    if r != 0 && atomic.AddInt32(&rw.readerWait, r) != 0 {
        runtime_SemacquireMutex(&rw.writerSem, false)
    }
    if race.Enabled {
        race.Enable()
        race.Acquire(unsafe.Pointer(&rw.readerSem))
        race.Acquire(unsafe.Pointer(&rw.writerSem))
    }
}
```

We can see that it calls a Mutex.Lock, hence it takes the same time of Mutex.Lock plus all the other stuff that it does.

We see a call to atomic.AddInt32, runtime_SemacquireMutex and other methods of the object `race`, this will have an overhead.

Comment: `race` is not an object, it's a package. And `race.Enabled` is a constant, which will not have runtime overhead, as if the race detector is not enabled, those branches are "compile-time dead".

Comment: Ok, race will not cause overhead, but the other ones? Especially runtime_SemacquireMutex will?

Comment: Yes, the rest is most likely causing some overhead (as mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

> the implementation of sync.Mutex is simpler: requires much less memory and is most likely faster.

It will be interesting to check if [CL 329769](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/329769) (for now an experiment by [Dmitry Vyukov](https://twitter.com/dvyukov/status/1406926048692953100)) will make it to Go 1.18:

> Thinking about following #golang RWMutex algo tweak
> **Makes writers as fast as readers and Mutex**:
>
> ```sh
> name                old time/op  new time/op  delta
> RWMutexWrite        22.3ns ± 0%  13.4ns ± 0%  -40.23%  (p=0.000 n=9+9)
> RWMutexRead         13.4ns ± 0%  13.0ns ± 1%   -2.40%  (p=0.000 n=10+10)
> RWMutexUncontended  42.1ns ± 0%  36.8ns ± 0%  -12.69%  (p=0.003 n=5+7)
> ```